# Keep track of threads in WCF application?

Tags: c#, wcf, iis-7

**Hi,**

How do I check amount of threads that my WCF service hosted in IIS7 uses? Iam suspecting that every user get atleas one thread and if so, then my WCF service will have 1000 threads and that does not sound good.

**BestRegards**

Comment: Do you have 1000 concurrent users?

Comment: go on and test it - you can even use the task-manager to find out how many threads a process has ... but to answer your question: IIS will handle this for you and no it won't create 1000 threads

Comment: Use perfmon.exe to monitor Process/Threads counter for w3wp.exe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using IIS, then threading is governed by IIS. Depending on which version of IIS (and whether Integrated Pipeline vs. Classic Mode) you get different flavours of threading.

Threading in IIS is very complex but best explained in [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tmarq/archive/2007/07/21/asp-net-thread-usage-on-iis-7-0-and-6-0.aspx). Having 1000 threads by itself is not a problem - IIS does a very good job optimising it for you. So **nothing wrong with 1000 IIS threads on a proper server.**

With this number of concurrent users, you probably need a server farm (2-3 servers) with a load balancer. Having said that, 1000 concurrent requests is the about the maximum of what a normal IIS can handle. If you have a beefy server, that should be enough.